# Декомпозиция на сущности

Tags: seo, архитектура, zend-framework

Использую Zend Framework 1 версии.
Интернет магазин, каталог. Есть товары и категории. Соответственно, на странице каталога представлена текущая категория и список подкатегорий и товаров.

Требуется задавать `title`, `meta` элементы HTML для SEO. Какое архитектурное решение лучше применить?

Думал добавить методы в модель категории, но по сути эти SEO описания не имеют отношения к категории, а только к представлению страницы. Тем более что правила формирования таких описаний очень сложны и тащить этот код в модели не хочется.

Comment: Он не должен быть в моделях, он должен быть в сервисе по генерации сео-описаний

Comment: А можно пример приветси интерфейса этого сервиса?

Comment: `generateModelDescription(Model $model); generateModelTitle(Model $model);`. Вы точно это хотели спросить?